# How to identify a Fox $H$ function from its Mellin transform?

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

I have obtained a Mellin transform

$
\mathcal{M}[f](s)= \frac{  \Gamma\left( 1-\frac{2-s}{a}\right)  \Gamma\left( \frac{2-s}{a}\right)  \Gamma\left( \frac{s}{2}\right)  {{2}^{s-1}}}{a \Gamma\left( 1-\frac{s}{2}\right) } =F(s)
$
which is a kernel of a Fox H-function by definition. I am trying to identify $f (t)= \mathcal{M}^{-1}[F](t)$ but am not very familiar with the notation.

My guess is

$
H^{2,1}_{0,1} \left(
\begin{array}{l}
(2/a, 1/a), (2/a, -1/a), (0,1/2) \\
 (1, -1/2)
\end{array} \right)
$

Can someone verify?